# Headline ( <h1> ) gets strange horizontal scroll on small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So, I have a div and inside `h1` headline which is working as it should. But when I resize my browser and when the last word "EVERYTHING" cannot be shown in one line I get a strange horizontal scroll and the word continues. I want it to be displayed just as the other two words. Actually, it should break on some point. I know I can just make text smaller and problem solved but I don't have that option.

Here is the code and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fYhZ3/5/

Note: resize the fiddle window for result

```
<style>
.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -9999;
  position: relative;
}
.jumbotron .headline {
  padding-top: 140px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h1>Run over </br>everything</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I can't understand the problem properly..Do you want to have 'everything' on same line?

Comment: I want 'everything' to break in two lines. Let's say 'Every' is on first line and 'thing' on the other.

Comment: "Everything" isn't two words so it's not going to break into two lines. You could explore with some CSS3 though, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: so, why didn't you use <br/> between 'every' and 'thing'?

Comment: Because it just has to be split on small screens. On bigger screens there is no need for breaking the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it should break on some point`, you can use the `word-wrap` property:

> Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line

Try this:

```
h1 {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYhZ3/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd need to tinker with **word-wrap** or 'word-wrap:break-word;'